# How to standardize date column having two different date formats into a column having a single date format in excel/sql/R

Tags: r, excel

I have a date column in my data with two different types of formats. Is there any method to standardize the date column so that it has only one type of date format?

Sample input data:

[image]

Desired output data

[image]

Comment: Pls post data, no pictures!

Comment: You don't have a `date` column, you got a `varchar` column with strings *formatted* like a timestamp. Btw, how do you know it's *Jan 12. 2010* instead of *Dec 1. 2010*?

Answer (score 3):

In R, you can use `anytime` library to do the same kind of conversions.

```
library(anytime) 
anytime(x)

#[1] "2010-12-01 08:26:00 +08" "2010-12-01 08:26:00 +08" "2010-12-01 08:26:00 +08" 
#    "2011-02-17 11:05:00 +08" "2011-02-17 11:05:00 +08"
```

This will convert it to time in your locale.

**data**

```
x <- c("12-01-2010 08:26", "12-01-2010 08:26", "12-01-2010 08:26", 
        "2/17/2011 11:05", "2/17/2011 11:05")
```

Comment: The OP wants `12-01-2010 08:26` converted to `2010-01-12` not `2010-12-01` :-)